# Math - getting x from system of equations on symbols

Tags: math, equation

At first sorry for bad english, Im deafinitely not specialized into math-english.

I have a system of equations:

[image]

I need to get clean x. I can use rest of symbols. Just get the x.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Is this a programming/code question, or a math question? Maybe better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hardly - it's little more than high school algebra.

Comment: @duffymo Math.SE doesn't have a lower limit.

Comment: It should.  As you can see, this is simplicity itself.

Comment: I post it here, becouse Im writting a program that counts x from this equation with given n, p, w and l. Im only 15, so before high school. Sorry for offtopic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two equations with two unknowns: x and y.  This is a pretty standard linear algebra problem.

```
n*x -p*y = w
x + y = I
```

Wolfram Alpha can give you the solution easily:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inv+%7B%7Bn%2C+-p%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1%7D%7D

Multiply that inverse by the right hand side and you'll have your answer:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inv+%7B%7Bn%2C+-p%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1%7D%7D*%7Bw%2C+I%7D

If that's too much for you, then I'd solve the second equation for y:

```
y = I -x
```

Substitute that value into the first equation:

```
n*x -p*(I-x) = w
```

Simplify by rearranging so only x remains on the left hand side:

```
(n+p)*x = w+p*I
```

Solve that equation for x:

```
x = (w+p*I)/(n+p)
```

Substitute that back into the other equation to get y:

```
y = I - (w+p*I)/(n+p)
```

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for offtopic.

Comment: No worries.  It doesn't bother me.  And your English is fine - far better than my alternative languages.  Good luck with your project.